# When in the life cycle is the init hook for subcomponents' creation in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, hook, lifecycle

In my component's template I have a bunch of subcomponents. Upon start, I want to execute a command to one of them. The reference to them is fetched as shown, including the different steps where I try to talk to them.

```
@ViewChildren(SubComponent) subs: QueryList<SubComponent>;

constructor(...) { console.log("constructed " + this.subs); }
ngOnInit()       { console.log("inited      " + this.subs); }

ngAfterContentInit()    { console.log("content init    " + this.subs); }
ngAfterContentChecked() { console.log("content checked " + this.subs); }
ngAfterViewInit()       { console.log("view init       " + this.subs.length); }
ngAfterViewChecked()    { console.log("view checked"     + this.subs.length); }
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm getting either nothing or zero in each call (on the first run). Finally, after a few nothings and zeros from `ngXxxChecked()` I'm getting the results and can react to it.

**However**, the reaction is supposed to only take place **first time** the subs are in existence. The approach above will do that **each time** the user interacts with the page.

One solution  is to set a timeout for the operation. It's an epically ugly hack that good programmers go to hell for. Another I can think of is to set a flag and only perform my action if it's not set. It's an ugly hack (we're not talking hell, but rather purgatory).

If I want to go to heaven, where source code roams freely and bugs kill themselves, what should I do?

Comment: I guess you have some `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` that creates the child components from async received data. In this case the components are created later, not at the initial lifecycle hook. When `ngAfterViewInit` is called, statically added components are created.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, I'm `*ngFor`ing them based on an a array in the component (I keep my settings in an array of type `SubsConfig[]`). Am I to understand by your comment that it's a no-go kind of situation? What would you suggest as a hackaround to it? The purgatory version, the hell version of something yet different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to have the subcomponent expose an event that emits its own instance within `ngOnInit`. The parent component can then listen to that event and grab the instance once it's available. Here is some basic code:

*SubComponent*

```
export class SubComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() name:string;
  @Output() init = new EventEmitter<SubComponent>();

  ngOnInit(){
    this.init.emit(this);
    this.init.complete();
  }
}
```

*ParentComponent* template

```
<sub-cmp *ngFor="let d of data" [name]="d" (init)="onSubInit($event)"></sub-cmp>
```

*ParentComponent* class:

```
onSubInit(sub:SubComponent){
  console.log(sub);
}
```

Now, within the `onSubInit` of the parent, you have an instance of your sub component to do whatever you want with.

[**Live demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qheyug)

[See the docs.](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)